# Unable to set static IP

Tags: networking, ethernet, static-ip

I've been trying to reconfigure my second Raspberry Pi after half a year since the first one. When I refer back my [old notes](http://yvonnezoe.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/r-pi-server-up-and-running-again-change-to-static-ip/) (which worked for the first one), I could not get the static IP working for the second R-Pi. Could it be possibly due to the different internet setting? (I'm currently using my campus LAN)

my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static

address 172.20.15.120
netmask 255.255.252.0
network 172.20.12.0
broadcast 172.20.15.255
gateway 172.20.15.254

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

However after I did a

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and `ifconfig`
it does not give me any address.

What's wrong with my configuration?
Another question, can I have both Ethernet and WiFi dongle connected?

Comment: And there's no other device with this ip present in your network ?

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in your config file - `broadcasr` should be changed to `broadcast`. Fix that and try again.

Also, please add `auto eth0` line to your config, preferably just before `iface eth0 inet static` line. This line tells Debian to start this interface automatically at boot. Without it, you have to run some commend like `ifup eth0` to configure your interface.

Comment: opps sorry. that's a typo here. but it's correct in my config file.

Comment: @yvonnezoe: Just spot another problem and updated my answer.

Comment: Even though I had all the static ip addresses information entered exactly as they should be, Raspberry PI refused to make any connection through wired or wireless connection. As soon as I entered `auto eth0` in the file, saved it and rebooted the PI, it automatically made the Internet connection and this time stayed connected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a campus LAN you should almost certainly be using dhcp, not static

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may have to kill dhclient if you don't restart after making the changes.

```
$ sudo killall dhclient
```